# Example of a Chaotic discrete dynamical system in dimension 2

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, chaos

I am looking for examples of discrete dynamical systems in dimension 2 that are :

1) Chaotic dynamical system in Devaney's sense in dimension 2 ? 
2) Chaotic dynamical system in Li-Yorke sense but not chaotic in Devaney's sense.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Kiki, regarding question 1), any Anosov diffeomorphism on $\mathbb{T}^2$ is Devaney chaotic.

Regarding question 2), the are minimal (i.e. every orbit is dense) Li-Yorke chaotic diffeomorphisms on $\mathbb{T}^2$, and since they are periodic point free, they cannot be Devaney chaotic.

The existence of such minimal diffeomorphisms can be proven as follows.

In a joint work with A. Koropecki https://arxiv.org/abs/0902.2474 we proposed the following definition: A homeomorphism $f\colon\mathbb{T}^2\to\mathbb{T}^2$ is said to be {weak spreading if for a lift $\hat f\colon\mathbb{R^2}\to\mathbb{R}^2$ of $f$, for any non-empty open set $U\subset\mathbb{R}^2$, any $\varepsilon>0$ and any $R>0$, there is an integer number $n>0$ such that $\hat{f}^{-n}(U)$ is $\varepsilon$-dense in a ball of radius $R$ (in $\mathbb{R}^2$).

By classical Baire's arguments one can show that for every weak spreading homeomorphism $f\colon\mathbb{T}^2\to\mathbb{T}^2$ there exists a Baire generic set $C_f\subset\mathbb{T}^2$ such that 
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:1}
\liminf_{n\to+\infty} d\big(f^n(x),f^n(y)\big) = 0, \quad\forall x,y\in C_f. 
\end{equation}

Now cosnsider the set $\mathcal{O}^\infty(\mathbb{T}^2) = \{h\circ T_\alpha\circ h^{-1} : \alpha\in\mathbb{T}^2,\ h\in\mathrm{Diff}^\infty(\mathbb{T}^2)\}$, where $T_\alpha\colon x\mapsto x+\alpha$ denotes the rigid translation and let $\overline{\mathcal{O}^\infty(\mathbb{T}^2)}$ denote its $C^\infty$-closure.

A. Fathi and M. Herman showed that there is a Baire generic set $\mathscr{C}_0\subset\overline{\mathcal{O}^\infty(\mathbb{T}^2)}$ such that every diffeomorphism of $\mathscr{C}_0$ is minimal. (see https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=TI&pg6=PC&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&review_format=html&s4=fathi%20AND%20HErman&s5=&s6=&s7=&s8=All&sort=Newest&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq&r=2&mx-pid=482843)

In https://arxiv.org/abs/0902.2474 we showed that there is a generic set $\mathscr{C}_1\subset\overline{\mathcal{O}^\infty(\mathbb{T}^2)}$ such that every element of $\mathscr{C}_1$ is weak spreading, and hence satisfies the above liminf condition.

Finally, it is known (sorry, I could not find a reference for this) that there is a generic set $\mathscr{C}_2\subset\overline{\mathcal{O}^\infty(\mathbb{T}^2)}$ such that every element of $\mathscr{C}_2$ is rigid, i.e. if $f\in\mathscr{C}_2$, then there is a sequence $n_j\to+\infty$ such that $f^{n_j}\to id$ in the $C^0$ topology, when $n_j\to+\infty$. On the other hand, it is clear that, if $f$ is rigid, then 
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:2}
\limsup_{n\to+\infty} d(f^n(x),f^n(y))>0, \quad\forall x,y\in\mathbb{T}^2,\ x\neq y.
\end{equation}

So, puting all these properties together one can see that every element of $\mathscr{C}_0\cap\mathscr{C}_1\cap\mathscr{C}_2$ is minimal and Li-York chaotic.

Answer (score 2):

For another answer to Question 1, consider Julia sets of holomorphic functions of one complex variable (e.g., polynomials or rational maps of degree $\geq 2$, or transcendental entire functions). Any such map is both Devaney and Li-Yorke chaotic on its Julia set.

A famous result of Misiurewicz shows that $J(\exp)=\mathbb{C}$ is a famous result of Misiurewicz. In particular, the complex exponential map $\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ is chaotic on the complex plane. (Compare my Monthly paper with Shen, [*The exponential map is chaotic*](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.4169/amer.math.monthly.122.10.919), [arxiv:1408.1129](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.1129).)

Similarly, for the rational map $z\mapsto (z^2+1)/(4z(z^2-1))$, the Julia set is the entire Riemann sphere. (See Beardon, Iteration of rational functions, Section 4.3.) So this is an analytic system on the sphere which is Devaney chaotic.

Answer (score 1):

1) [Chaos in the sense of Devaney for two-dimensional time-varying generalized symbolic dynamical systems](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/317217816_Chaos_in_the_Sense_of_Devaney_for_Two-Dimensional_Time-Varying_Generalized_Symbolic_Dynamical_Systems)

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
It seem to me like the system is non autonomous right ?